# Avocado not growing at all after 2 months

Tags: avocado

I've propagated this avocado seed in water for 3-4 weeks, untill at root was about 10 cm long. Planted in soil about 2 months ago, day temp is 20-30c, soil always wet. Is it ever going to grow, or should i try with a new seed ? [image]

Answer (score 1):

Your Avocado seed may have been put in the soil a little soon, but it might yet grow! The soil seems a little dry and too compact.

Would suggest trying another seed, while continue trying with your present seed, as your present seed may yet sprout! And to consider soil that's a bit richer. Also, if try a new seed, would suggest letting the root develop more fully & until your Avocado sprouts and begins growing a bit, before carefully placing it in moist soil, with some coarse gravel in the bottom and holes in the bottom for good aeration & good drainage.